# Using Liquibase and Spring Boot

Tags: spring, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I have a Spring Boot application and want to use Liquibase to generate the changelogs for my JPA entities. However, I encounter different issues, depending on my approach.

- My first approach is to use the *diff* goal of the maven plugin. The url is my H2 development database with the H2 driver and the reference URL is something like "*hibernate:spring:myBasePackage.myEntityPackage?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect*" with the driver "*liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.connection.HibernateDriver*". In that case Liquibase seems to recognize my entities, but prints the differences to the console. Also the differences do not have the form of a changelog file.
- My second approach would be to use the *generateChangeLog* goal of the maven plugin. In this case my url is "*hibernate:spring:myBasePackage.myEntityPackage?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect*" with the driver "*liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.connection.HibernateDriver*. In this case I am getting an error "*Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist*". This error can be found in both the Spring an the Liquibase issue trackers, but it seems like it is always said that this error is already fixed.
- My third approach is basically like the second, but in this case I am using a "*hibernate:classic*" url with an implementation of "*CustomClassicConfigurationFactory*", which registers my annotated classes explicitly. This does work. However, in this case I have to do this in my application-jar. I have to add my application-jar as a dependency for the maven-plugin. Thus I have to build my application-jar (and install it to the local Maven repository), before I can generate the changelogs. This seems to be cumbersome.

My questions are:

- Is there an easier way to generate the changelogs for JPA entities in a Spring boot based application?
- Why are the first two approaches not working?
- Is there a way to simplify the third approach?

I am using:

- Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE
- Liquibase-Hibernate4 3.6
- Liquibase 3.5.3

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the first approach using `liquibase:diff` , the change set for the entities (create table change set) will not be generated since `liquibase` do not assume new `jpa` entity as change.

In the second approach `generateChangeLog`, it generates the change log from the given data base.It won't look into your `jpa` entities.

In order to generate the ddl scripts for your jpa entities , just submit the following to your jpa properties

```
<property key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action">drop-and-create</property>
<property key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target">./ddl/create.sql</property>
<property key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.drop-target">./ddl/drop.sql</property>
```

The above will generate the scripts the ddl folder under the root folder.

You can check the other properties here https://thoughts-on-java.org/standardized-schema-generation-data-loading-jpa-2-1/

Comment: javax.property is not liquibase.The first two points are using liquibase.